# How to call value of variable which is in one function to another function in as 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, function

I have taken variable in one function and want to use that value in another function.
Please give me example...

Answer (score 0):

I have not quite understand you pb, but `return` you `variable` from the `function` and pass it as a `parameter` to the another `function`.

```
function foo():String {
 var tmp:String="hello";
 //...
 return tmp;
}

function bar(value:String):void{
 //...
 trace(value); // will trace "hello"
}

var str:String=foo();
bar(str);

// or

bar( foo() );
```

Comment: hi patrick, I have posted detailed program, Please go through and suggest:
Question: Making a custom glossary
tags: flash, flex

Comment: Added an answer to your previous question

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a variable defined within the body of a function in another function, then you can return the value you're after from the first function.

Here's an example that loops through a provided array and returns the index of the first matched number (`find`).

```
function iterate(find:uint, values:Array):int
{
    var i:uint = 0;
    for(i; i<values.length; i++)
    {
        if(values[i] == find) return i;
    }

    return -1;
}

function doThings():void
{
    var iterations:int = iterate(10, [5, 2, 5, 6, 10, 17, 4]);
    trace(iterations); // output: 4
}

doThings();
```

If you need multiple values then you could store this in an object or array and return that:

```
function getpos():Object
{
    var obj:Object =
    {
        x: stage.mouseX,
        y: stage.mouseY,
        side: mouseX < stage.stageWidth / 2 ? "left" : "right"
    };

    return obj;
}


stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _click);
function _click(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(getpos().side, getpos().x, getpos().y);
}
```